# server side oauth: What to do with the tokens received

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

This is my first time doing a full implementation of server side OAuth (as described here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) and I am getting a bit confused as to what to do with the tokens after receiving them from the auth provider. I can see a few options

1. Send it to the user for local storage and send it to the db. have the frontend send it in http headers on every request and compare it with the one in the db to authenticate.
2. Send it to the database and work out some other form of authentication through a jwt or cookie.
3. something else?

1 would be my preferred way, but something feels wrong about it...IDK what, while 2 feels a little wasteful because I will have to come up with an entirely different auth mechanism and then just pull the token from the db and refresh and use it as normal anyway...

What is an acceptable flow for this part of the application?

Comment: What is your reason for using OAuth2 and for getting tokens? What tokens do you want to get (access token, refresh token, ID token)?

Comment: the reason is for the provider API access and streamlining of the signup process. I am getting access, refresh, and ID

Comment: So you want to access Google services from your backend. And what is your frontend? Is it a single page application or some more traditional HTML+JavaScript? Do you need a token there just for the session identification?

Comment: its a react single page app. Would be nice to have some basic user info that is in the token as well

Answer (score 1):

First, you should decide which part of your application will have a role of the OAuth2 client. If you have a React SPA as a frontend, I would suggest you to make it the client and use the [Implicit grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) OAuth2 flow (designed for browser apps) instead of the [Auth code grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1). This way, the SPA initiates the authentication and it receives an ID token (to identify the user) and an access token to call [Google services](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent).

Then there is a question how to identify a user at the backend. I would use the ID token for that - the backend will have to check the Google signature and that the audience of the token is the client ID of your application. Based on this ID token, you can either issue your own token (just for the identification of your frontend user), create a backend session or to keep sending the Google ID token with each request.

Comment: this makes sense, but if I am going to need API access, I don't see the point in creating my own authentication scheme and then coming back to the token for the API. I would like to use the google ID token, but they are only good for one hour...How would the frontend flow look like when getting another token? use JS to check expiry time and redirect the user around again? what if there is a bad/expired token sent to the server? How should the frontend handle that without automatically failing?

Comment: if you need a new ID token at the frontend, you can use the `prompt=none` request parameter for the `/auth` endpoint. This way, you can get a new token without the user interaction - in an iframe, without the user noticing the token change. As long as the SSO session is valid at Google. So when the frontend receives a token, it schedules a task for getting a new one before the token expires.

Comment: ok thanks for the help. I will need other providers too...This provider looks like they only offer the implicit flow, but I can't be sure because they are so similar. Can you verify if this is the implicit flow... (http://open.wechat.com/cgi-bin/newreadtemplate?t=overseas_open/docs/web/login/login#login_login)

Comment: No, it's the Auth code grant. The Implicit flow doesn't require a client secret and the `response_type` auth URL param has a value of either`token` or `id_token token` or `id_token` (depending on what token you want to get).

Answer (score 0):

The first question I think you need to answer is what are you using the OAuth tokens for. Before we look at that question, let's understand what tokens the server side OAuth flow or Authorization Code OAuth flow generally give you (based on the scopes you specify).

1. Access Token: This is a bearer token (meaning if you have the token, you have access) and that's the token you use when querying that provider's APIs or trying to access that provider's resources. Depending on the flow that is used to obtain the token, the token can have different expiration times.
2. Identity Token: This is a signed JWT token that you can introspect and obtain *identity* information about the user, such as their username, email, etc.
3. Refresh Token: Used to renew the Access token

Access to these tokens can allow you to do many things:

- access the provider's resources on behalf of the user
- identify the user
- get more info on the user by querying provider's APIs
- establish a session between the user and backend
  etc.

But you need to understand the value of the tokens when you use them. 
For example, a server side flow OAuth gives long terms access tokens that should only exist on a `trusted` client (such as the backend and not the frontend). If your use case requires access to provider's resources from the frontend (considered `low trust` client) you should use an implicit OAuth flow.

Regarding session management, again you should understand that the OAuth access token gives the bearer certain privileges (depending on the scope specified) that you are giving away in case of session compromise. So unless you have to for other reasons, in general it's a good idea not to use the access token as a session management cookie.

Regarding the user identity, that's generally a pretty short term token, so once the token has been verified (signature, state and expiry) then you should cache the user identity somewhere backend or in a signed cookie etc.